# reading text of a text box

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on designing a user profile web page in asp.net using c#.

I first load the values of text boxes from database and put them in the text box:

```
txt_Name.Text = "somestring";
```

The user can then change the text in the text box to modify their profile.

However when I read `txt_Name.Text` it shows me the "original" value instead of what the user entered.

More clearly:

1. First I set the value of a text box to something:
   `txt_Name.Text = "somestring";`
2. Then the user changes the value of the text box to something else in the gui
3. Then I read the value of text box:
   `Response.Write(txt_Name.Text);`

In **3** the value is the one from **1** instead of the one from **2**

Comment: Post some code, both the ASPX and the code-behind, please, so we can see where you're going wrong and help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you aren't checking the Page.IsPostBack property (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx) when you are setting the initial textbox value, so it is always being set no matter how the page is invoked.

```
private void Page_Load()
{
  if (!IsPostBack)
  {
     txt_Name.Text = "somestring";
  }
}
```

Comment: That was the problem. Thank you

Comment: +1.  Nice...  I wouldn't have gotten that from the bit of code that was posted.!

Answer (score 1):

Its all in the page life cycle have a look at this page

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Comment: +1 for understanding what was going on, but @devdigital's answer was better - more specific and provided exactly the info needed, rather than a link that the asker would have had to read completely to get what was happaning. However, the page lifecycle is SO critical that I'm voting you up just for bringing it up.

Comment: Thanks, i started typing the answer before he added more detail. I have had tons of issues not knowing where to start looking. if i knew about page life cycle in the start it would have saved me hours, and its not only applicable to the current question. :)